# Animation of an ImageView to move in a semi-circle (Android)

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to learn a little bit about animations and so decided to get an `ImageView` to go across the screen from left to right, which I achieved with:

```
TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 180, 0, 0);
            mAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1); 
            mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            myImageView.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

So, I decided to take on a new challenge. Once the image has gone from left to right, I wanted to try and get the image to return to the start position by arching back from right to left to its starting position (basically, a complete semi-circle). However, once the image has reached the end of the x-axis at position 180, I get stuck.

After reading about different methods for animation, I opted to try out `ValueAnimator`:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); // values from 0 to 1
            animator.setDuration(1000); // 1 seconds duration from start to end position
            animator.setRepeatCount(-1);
            animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                    float value = (Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue());

                    myImageView.setTranslationX((float)(180.0 * Math.sin(value*Math.PI)));
                    myImageView.setTranslationY((float)(80.0 * Math.cos(value*Math.PI)));

                }
            });
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                {
                    // done
                }
            });
            animator.start();
```

However, I am unable to get the positioning correct. I do have a semi-circle (good), however, it is moving the image like a backward C rather than a straight line left to right and then arching back to its starting position (bad).

I am not sure if I should be using `AnimatorSet` to link the left to right movement and the arching back movement together to create one whole animation...

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to achieve what I have described?

Comment: that should be quite easy with MotionLayout

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for the suggestion and I will consider it in future when using constraint layouts. However, I wondered if there was a solution based on not having to use a constraint layout.